# How can I use swiperefreshlayout in a library module with Android Studio?

Tags: android

I'd like to use swiperefreshlayout in a library module.I already created a library module.As we know,I'd suppose to import com.android.support.recyclerview-v7 into my library module before I use it.But the problem is AS cannot find this component:
[image]

what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Your error shows that `SwipeRefreshLayout` class is not found from your dependencies.
By default `support-v4` jar dependency should be added at project level dependency in android studio. So, when you create a new library module it should be inherited.
Anyway still if you are missing support-v4 dependency,then in your library module there should `library.iml` (yourlibmodule.iml) file. You can add following line in that iml file.

```
<orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="support-v4-23.1.1" level="project" />
```